# Change page post status to draft based on acf field

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I’m kinda newbie to coding, I have just made a new wordpress site that uses advanced custom fields on backend (all fields are global fields in added options menu) from where front end pulls the values to let our client customize their template-like website. It’s almost ready, but I’m facing a problem that I can’t solve without coding probably, based on my research. I would like to implement a custom chechbox field on the backend where the client can turn on and off Blog page usage. The idea is that, when the checkbox is thicked ( It has any value) the Blog page’s post status should be change to published, but when It’s unthicked ( It has no value) the Blog page’s post status should be changed to draft. I’m completely virgin in coding, so I’m stucked with this and ask for help here. Is anybody have a template code or some kind of ready made solution to do this? If there is no such thing, could someone suggest a site or guide that helps to build the code, or at least a way where should I start if I have 0 php coding skill? Thanks before!

Comment: What do you want exactly: a new backend checkbox that will update the post status? Or a new checkbox that will make the post displayed or not on frontend (without changing the real post status)?

Comment: The first one, create a custom checkbox field on backend that updates the page's post status based on It has or has not any value.